Can Etherlink contracts be accessible to L1?
I'm still looking to implement a basic Tezos smart contract that return a trusted random number.
Etherlink just added to the documentation their compatibility with Pyth Entropy.
I have experience building on Tezos, but I don't really know Solidity.
Is there a way to create a random number generator using Pyth Entropy and use it natively on Tezos L1 ?

Right now, the only possible on-chain communication between Tezos Layer 1 and Etherlink is depositing and withdrawing assets (XTZ and FA tokens).
So the answer would reasonably be no as far as I can tell. (Maybe we could imagine in theory something with FA tokens carrying numbers, and an off-chain event-based triggering system, but it would be very far fetch and super impractical with the two-weeks withdrawing period when sending from Etherlink to Tezos Layer 1.)
But there is hope! The current Tezos X roadmap (see here for the full article) includes Michelson support in the same roll-up as Etherlink in 2025, so that most Tezos Layer 1 applications can run next to Etherlink, with communication between the two worlds at the level of layer-2 blocks, or maybe even as internal transactions?

Thank you Nicolas, I will create a Pyth Entropy contract on Etherlink testnet and see where i go from here
